# Where can one disable the start menu items for clients of an AD using GPMC?

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy, active-directory, security

I have a windows AD server setup with a few user groups, however I need to add a policy so that any user that log into the domain items or the entire start menu should be disabled. 
I can use Group Policy editor to do it locally (gpedit.msc) however It would be ideal if the policy could be set to a group using the Group Policy Management Console,

Has anyone managed to implement specific polices to a object in GPMC?

Answer (score 1):

yes, to edit these settings create a GPO and navigate to user configuration, Administrative Templates, Start Menu and Taskbar. You'll find the settings you are looking for there. Using GPMC, you link the GPO to the OU where your users are. Make sure you test the settings first using a test OU.

Answer (score 0):

Another question is how restricted are you looking to make the user experience?

Some other Group Policy Areas you might wish to look at:

User Configuration | Administrative Templates | Desktop (to control how they can access and manipulate their desktop)

User Configuration | Administrative Templates | Control Panel (to lock down what kind of system settings they can look at and change)

User Configuration | Administrative Templates | System (to do things like turn off command line and other methods of bypassing your restrictions)